# I can't write \dfrac or \tfrac in the curly brackets

Tags: nodes, fractions

I want to write a fraction for a point on an axis. 
`node at (1,0) {$\dfrac{1}{2}$};`

I'm able to do it with `\frac` but not the other two types of fraction code like `\dfrac` or `\tfrac`.

Is there a reason for this or a solution for that?

Comment: Did you load `amsmath` (or its extension `mathtools`)?

Answer (score 4):

<sup>Too long for a comment.</sup>

The following example uses TikZ and the fraction commands provided by package `amsmath`. The example compiles without errors or warnings:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\tikz\path
  (1, 0) node {$\frac{1}{2}$}
  (2, 0) node {$\tfrac{3}{4}$}
  (3, 0) node {$\dfrac{5}{6}$}
;
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]